# Request body doesn't comply with interface, but doesn't return error

Tags: typescript, express

I have this NewTransactionPayload interface, whereby I want to make sure that my request body only contains this object. But apparently, upon hosting, I don't see any complaint from TypeScript. Why?

```
// interfaces
interface NewTransactionPayload {
   transactionAmount: Number;
   transactionDate: String;
   transactionWallet: String;
   transactionPocket: String;
   transactionTag: String;
   transactionDetails: String;
}


transactionsRouter.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    try {
        const newTransaction:NewTransactionPayload = req.body;
        // const newTransaction = body;
        res.status(201).json(newTransaction);
    } catch (err){
        res.status(400).json({error: `Bad request. ${err}`})
    }
});
```

Comment: TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime. It _cannot_; all type metadata is erased in transpilation to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that is designed to catch errors at compile time. This means that TypeScript can detect syntax errors and type safety violations before your code is executed, which can help to prevent runtime errors.

However, TypeScript does not perform runtime type checking. This is because the types of variables and expressions are removed during compilation. This is done to improve performance, as runtime type checking can add overhead.

If you need to perform runtime type checking, you can use a third-party library like Zod. Zod is a library that provides runtime type validation for TypeScript. It can be used to validate the types of variables, expressions, and objects at runtime.

Ref: https://www.totaltypescript.com/tutorials/zod/zod-section/number